# I am getting error message "Failed to load resource" when working with Dreamweaver and MAMP5 (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, macos, mamp, dreamweaver

I am working with Dreamweaver and MAMP5 on a Macbook Pro.  I am starting my first database.  However, I am getting this error message:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

The code I have inserted is as follows:

On PHP file:

```
require_once("DB.php");

if (isset($_POST["Submit"])){
    if (!empty($_POST["EName"]) && !empty($_POST["SSN"])) { }
```

On DB.php file

```
$DSN = 'mysql:host= localhost; dbname: record';
$ConnectingDB = new PDO ($DSN, 'root', '');
```

Please help.

Comment: Probably uncaught error in the server code. Surround code with 3 backticks on their own line if posting it on SO

Comment: 500 server error is the generic response shown on the front end to mean some problem with the server or code.  Your web server, and/or PHP logs, will show you exactly what the problem was.  You are working blind if you are not using your logs.